# Seleccionar registro de una BD dos veces pero con distintas condiciones

Tags: sql

Estoy trabajando en SQL, tengo 3 tablas como se ve en la imagen, en la tabla TipoDireccionEntidad tengo si es email o dirección de domicilio, lo que requiero es mostrar el nombre (en entidad), la dirección de correo y la dirección de domicilio.

Tengo el código por separado pero necesito que me devuelva 4 columnas: ID, NOmbre, Direccion, Email, en una sola consulta. Espero que se pueda entender y me puedan ayudar

```html
select distinct en.Id, en.Nombre, de.Nombre Direccion from Persona.Entidad as en
inner join Persona.DireccionEntidad as de on de.EntidadId=en.Id
where de.TipoDireccionEntidadId=1

select distinct en.Id, en.Nombre, de.Nombre Email from Persona.Entidad as en
inner join Persona.DireccionEntidad as de on de.EntidadId=en.Id
where de.TipoDireccionEntidadId=2
```

[image: Diseño de Tablas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de varias maneras.

Para el escenario no voy a usar el esquema Persona y directamente uso el dbo.

```
Create table Entidad (id int, nombre varchar(100))
Create table DireccionEntidad(Id int, EntidadId int, Nombre varchar(100), TipoDireccionEntidadId int)
-- la tercera tabla no es necesaria, porque ya conoces los ids.

Insert into Entidad (id, nombre)
Values
(1,'Eva'),
(2,'Ana'),
(3,'Bea');
Insert into DireccionEntidad(Id, EntidadId,Nombre, TipoDireccionEntidadId)
values
(1,2,'Ana1@email.es',2),
(2,2,'Calle Ana',1),
(3,3,'Bea@email.es',2),
(4,1,'Calle Eva',1);
```

Una opción es usar un `Left join` y en el mismo aplicarle el motivo de la unión.

```
select en.Id, 
       en.Nombre, 
       de1.Nombre As Direccion, 
       de2.Nombre As Email
from Entidad as en
left join DireccionEntidad as de1 on de1.EntidadId=en.Id And de1.TipoDireccionEntidadId = 1
left join DireccionEntidad as de2 on de2.EntidadId=en.Id And de2.TipoDireccionEntidadId = 2
```

Así puedes relacionar varias veces, otorgándoles un alias diferente, a cada una de las tablas.

| Id | Nombre | Direccion | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Eva | Calle Eva | null |
| 2 | Ana | Calle Ana | Ana1@email.es |
| 3 | Bea | null | Bea@email.es |

Tienes que tener en cuenta que si una persona tiene varios emails o direcciones, tendrás repetidas las filas de persona.

```
Insert into DireccionEntidad(Id, EntidadId,Nombre, TipoDireccionEntidadId)
values
(5,2,'Ana2@email.es',2);
```

| Id | Nombre | Direccion | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Eva | Calle Eva | null |
| 2 | Ana | Calle Ana | Ana1@email.es |
| 2 | Ana | Calle Ana | Ana2@email.es |
| 3 | Bea | null | Bea@email.es |

Pero si añades otra dirección para Ana entonces, ¿a que dirección se le otorga cada uno de sus emails?.

**Opción Operador Apply**

Cuando solo quieres uno, puedes hacer uso del operador apply.

```
select en.Id, 
       en.Nombre, 
       dire.Nombre As Direccion, 
       email.Nombre As Email
from Entidad as en
outer apply (
    Select top(1) * from DireccionEntidad de1
    where de1.EntidadId = en.id
    and de1.TipoDireccionEntidadId = 1
    order by de1.Id-- este order by es con el que juegas para que solo sea 1 
) as dire
outer apply (
    Select top(1) * from DireccionEntidad de2
    where de2.EntidadId = en.id
    and de2.TipoDireccionEntidadId = 2
    order by de2.Id-- este order by es con el que juegas para que solo sea 1 
) as email
```

Dentro de los conjuntos que hay entre paréntesis, y que solo devuelven un resultado por cada id del conjunto exterior, tienes un order by para explicitar cual es de los que haya prefieres.

[Operador Apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/)

Comment: Funciono bien, la duda que tengo es como puedo hacer si tengo varias direcciones y varios email de cada persona. como puedo seleccionar solo 1, porque la instrucción DISTINCT no me funciona en esos casos

Comment: Es que distinct no es para eso. Distinct te trae solo las filas que estén repetidas en todos las columnas como 1. Y Si quieres solo 1, ¿Cual?. El mas largo, el mas corto......, el del dominio a el del b, no importa, cualquiera.......Eso no es un escenario claro. Piensalo. Edita la pregunta añadiendo las filas necesarias, para lo que pides y así podremos darte una respuesta apropiada.

Comment: Te he puesto una solución, para solo 1 de cada.